# collect all directories matching criteria from directory tree in python

Tags: python, directory, filesystems, shutil

How can I collect all directories that match a criteria (like 'contain a file named foo.txt') recursively from a directory tree? something like:

```
def has_my_file(d):
   return ('foo.txt' in os.listdir(d))

walk_tree(dirname, criterion=has_my_file)
```

for the tree:

```
home/
  bob/
    foo.txt
  sally/
    mike/
      foo.txt
```

`walk_tree` should return:

```
['home/bob/', 'home/sally/mike']
```

is there such a function in python libraries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`os.walk`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk):

```
import os

result = []
for parent, ds, fs in os.walk(dirname):
    if 'foo.txt' in fs:
        result.append(parent)
```

Using list comprehension:

```
result = [parent for parent, ds, fs in os.walk(dirname) if 'foo.txt' in fs]
```

Comment: should be os.walk not os.walkdir

Comment: @user248237dfsf, You're right. fixed that. Thank you for pointing that.